# What does “brimstone” mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Then, stepping into his extended hand, and condescending to be held out at arm’s length, he gave vent to a succession of sounds, not unlike the drawing of some eight or ten dozen of long corks, and again asserted his brimstone birth and parentage with great distinctness.

Barnaby Rudge by Charles Dickens

Comment: *Brimstone* is sulfur, a sign of God's wrath in the Hebrew Bible (e.g., Gen 19:24-25) and associated with the fires of hell in the Christian tradition: in Revelation those bearing the mark of the Beast are "cast alive into a lake of fire burning with brimstone".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your passage

> **brimstone**

refers to the place of birth of the bird in Barnaby's hand.
To have a

> **brimstone birth**

is to be borne a devil, which is a reference to a few paragraphs earlier when the bird is saying

> "I'm a devil, I'm a devil, I'm a devil"